# How to use chef to update-alternatives for java using execute?

Tags: java, ruby, linux, ubuntu, chef-infra

I am having syntax errors and I am unsure how to resolve them.  In the roles file I have defined the fallowing:

```
default_attributes(
  'jdk' => {
    'version' => '1.8.0_31'
  },
  'java' => {
    'home' => '/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_31'
  },
)
```

I try to use the java home in the following, but it fails to run

```
execute "update_alt_java" do
  command "update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "#{node['java']['home']}/bin/java" 1"
  action :creates
end
```

I get the following  error

```
SyntaxError
-----------
/etc/chef/src/cookbooks/jdk/recipes/default.rb:50: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
...tives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "#{node['java']['home...
...                               ^
/etc/chef/src/cookbooks/jdk/recipes/default.rb:50: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end
...--install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "#{node['java']['home']}/bi...
```

Answer (score 6):

Are you using the community [java cookbook](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/java)?

It includes an LWRP for this purpose:

```
# set alternatives for java and javac commands
java_alternatives "set java alternatives" do
    java_location '/usr/local/java'
    bin_cmds ["java", "javac"]
    action :set
end
```

## Update: "my_java" wrapper cookbook example

The following is a sample cookbook called "my_java" designed to install the oracle JDK on Ubuntu:

```
├── attributes
│   └── java.rb   <-- Used for java cookbook attribute overrides
├── Berksfile
├── Berksfile.lock
├── metadata.rb
├── README.md
└── recipes
    └── default.rb
```

After running chef the oracle JDK is intalled

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_31"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_31-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.31-b07, mixed mode)
```

Notes:

- This cookbook relies on overriding attributes. This could just as easily be done from a chef environment or role.

### metadata.rb

```
name             'my_java'
maintainer       'Mark O''Connor'
maintainer_email 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
license          'All rights reserved'
description      'Installs/Configures my_java'
long_description 'Installs/Configures my_java'
version          '0.1.0'

depends "apt"
depends "java"
```

### attribute/java.rb

```
normal['java']['jdk_version'] = '8'
normal['java']['install_flavor'] = 'oracle'
normal['java']['oracle']['accept_oracle_download_terms'] = true
```

Notes:

- By default java will install openJDK. These overrides specify v8 of OracleJDK

### recipes/default.rb

```
include_recipe "apt"
include_recipe "java"
```

Notes:

- Obviously the "apt" cookbook only applies to Debian based linux. This recipe would require minor tweaking to work on redhat as well.

Comment: I couldn't get java from oracle to install using that cookbook because oracle doesn't allow you download the file using the cookie.  So, I was trying to do it manually by creating a new cookbook just for this instance.  If you have an idea how to use the java cookbook without having to create a repository, I would like to know.

Comment: @pitchblack408 Example given on how to install Oracle using the "Java" cookbook. The documentation states that the cookbook is fully aware of the cookie problem (see: https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/java)

Comment: Hi. I use cookbook from https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/java
linux ok. but on window i can't install i have error bad URI. plz help me

Comment: @Luna Looks like on windows you must provide a URL for the java package binary. See: https://github.com/agileorbit-cookbooks/java/blob/master/attributes/default.rb#L41

Comment: .thank so much but it dont run. have new error windown_package[tar] T_T

Comment: "java_alternatives "set java alternatives" do" where will this come in cookbook ?

after running "chef-client --local-mode --runlist 'recipe[chef]' ", it gives me error of missing cookbook : windows

Comment: @goCode Best posed as a new question. At first glance your problem appears to be missing cookbook in the chef server

Comment: Ok. Thank you so much for all the help Mark.

Answer (score 2):

You should escape all double quotes in your command string, because it starts and ends with double quotes.

There is no action :creates for execute resource. The action should be :run.

```
execute "update_alt_java" do
  command "update-alternatives --install \"/usr/bin/java\" \"java\" \"#{node['java']['home']}/bin/java\" 1"
  action :run
end
```

But you don't want to run this resource on every chef run, so you should come up with some kind of condition, when it should be run (using only_if, not_if statements).