# Can the java cookbook be used to install a local copy of oracle java?

Tags: java, ruby, chef-infra, chef-solo

I have been trying to learn chef recently because I was planning on using it for deploying server config and server application software.  I am having issues understanding how to use other people's cookbooks.  For example, I want to deploy JDK8u31.  I can't figure it out how to implement this cookbook. https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/java

I read the instructions and I see the following

Simply include the java recipe wherever you would like Java installed, such as a run list (recipe[java]) or a cookbook (include_recipe 'java')

I tried to

```
include_recipe 'java'
```

inside my cookbook called common_java_server

then

```
directory '/usr/lib/jvm/' do
  owner 'root'
  group 'root'
  mode '0644'
end




java_ark "jdk" do
    url 'http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u31/jdk-8u31-linux-x64.bin'
    checksum  'a8603fa62045ce2164b26f7c04859cd548ffe0e33bfc979d9fa73df42e3b3365'
    app_home '/usr/lib/jvm/'
    bin_cmds ["java", "javac"]
    action :install
end

# set alternatives for java and javac commands
java_alternatives "set java alternatives" do
    java_location '/usr/local/java'
    bin_cmds ["java", "javac"]
    action :set
end
```

This is the error I get

```
Recipe Compile Error in /etc/chef/src/cookbooks/common/recipes/java_dev_server.rb
====
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [java cookbook](https://github.com/agileorbit-cookbooks/java) is designed to support the installation of different Java variants. It's behaviour is controlled by node attributes. The defaults are in the [cookbook](https://github.com/agileorbit-cookbooks/java/blob/master/attributes/default.rb) and will install the OpenJDK.

So, to install the oracle JDK you need to specify alternative overrides and these are discussed in the [README](https://github.com/agileorbit-cookbooks/java#oracle)

How do you do this? In chef you have at least two options:

1. Wrapper cookbook
2. Role

For an example of a wrapper cookbook I refer you to my other answer.

- [How to use chef to update-alternatives for java using execute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28775225/how-to-use-chef-to-update-alternatives-for-java-using-execute/28775684#28775684)

For an example role try this:

```
{
  "name": "java",
  "description": "Oracle java role",
  "override_attributes": {
    "java": {
      "jdk_version": 8,
      "install_flavor": "oracle",
      "oracle": {
        "accept_oracle_download_terms": true
      }
    }
  },
  "run_list": [
    "recipe[apt]",
    "recipe[java]"
  ]
}
```

Add this role to the run-list of your node and the OracleJDK will be installed.

---

## Test Kitchen project that tests the install of OracleJDK

The following is a test kitchen example that will install and test a "java" role against both ubuntu and centos

```
├── Berksfile
├── .kitchen.yml
├── roles
│   └── java.json
└── test
    └── integration
        └── default
            └── serverspec
                └── java_spec.rb
```

Install chefDK, vagrant and run the following command

```
kitchen test
```

Notes:

- The simplest way to get test kitchen running is to install both [vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/) and [chefdk](https://downloads.chef.io/chef-dk/)

### Berksfile

```
source "https://supermarket.chef.io"

cookbook "apt"
cookbook "java"
```

### .kitchen.yml

```
---
driver:
  name: vagrant

provisioner:
  name: chef_zero
  require_chef_omnibus: 12.0.3
  client_rb:
    "Ohai::Config[:disabled_plugins] = [:GCE] #": 

platforms:
  - name: ubuntu-12.04
  - name: centos-6.4

suites:
  - name: default
    run_list:
      - role[java]
```

Notes:

- The special role "java" is added to the node run-list.
- This example disables the "gce" plugin. See [issue 624](https://github.com/test-kitchen/test-kitchen/issues/624).

### roles/java.json

See above

### test/integration/default/serverspec/java_spec.rb

```
require 'serverspec'

# Required by serverspec
set :backend, :exec

describe file('/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle-amd64/release'), :if => os[:family] == "ubuntu" do
  it { should contain 'JAVA_VERSION="1.8.0_31"' }
end

describe file('/usr/lib/jvm/java/release'), :if => os[:family] == "redhat" do
  it { should contain 'JAVA_VERSION="1.8.0_31"' }
end
```

Comment: "Add this role to the run-list of your node and the OracleJDK will be installed."  where to add this in cookbook ?

Comment: This example uses a role, not a cookbook. I included an alternative answer using a wrapper cookbook, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28775225/how-to-use-chef-to-update-alternatives-for-java-using-execute/28775684#28775684