# How to use chef to install JDK8 on RHEL

Tags: chef-infra, java, chef-recipe

I have been looking at this for help : 
https://github.com/agileorbit-cookbooks/java. I don't know how to run recipes from this cookbook.

I am completely new to chef.

I have gone through the basic chef tutorial and I know to do this :

```
chef-apply $recipe.rb
```

I need help in creating a recipe to install for JDK 7/8. I don't need a cookbook. I have setup the chef-dk on my machine, and tried out a few examples from their learning website.

**EDIT#1 :**

Looking at the Java-Cookbook, I don't follow the README file. I am unable to run the recipe for JDK-8 install.

*What I am trying is as follows :*

- cd into the java cookbook
- cd into the recipes folder
- chef-apply $recipe-name.rb
- this is giving me errors

*What I want to do :*

- Install JDK8 using chef from the internet

***I have tried the following things listed below :***

I try to do this :

```
chef-apply default.rb
```

I get the following errors :

```
FATAL : Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
FATAL : NoMethodError: undefined method '[]' for nil"NilClass
```

The 'chef-stacktrace.out' contains :

[image]

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking for at all...You talk about the java cookbook and then say you don't need a cookbook.

Comment: @Tensibai - i am trying to figure out how to run the recipe from java cookbook, once I have downloaded it. Pls help.

Comment: @Tensibai - I have added an edit, i hope this makes it a little more clear where i am stuck.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can the java cookbook be used to install a local copy of oracle java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28776899/can-the-java-cookbook-be-used-to-install-a-local-copy-of-oracle-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm really unsure of where you're stuck, quoting the README for the java cookbook (the link you gave):

You have to make a wrapper cookbook with:

- metadata.rb

  ```
  [...] # Usual data in a cookbook

  depends "java"
  ```
- attribute/default.rb

  ```
  default["java"]["install_flavor"] = "oracle"
  default["java"]["jdk_version"] = "7"
  default['java']['jdk']['7']['x86_64']['url'] = "http://you_local_host/package.tgz" # Oracle does not allow to directly download the jdk
  ```
- recipes/default.rb

  ```
  include_recipe "java"
  ```

And then add this cookbook to your target runlist.

Best idea would be to start with the learning material [here](https://learn.chef.io/index.html) about what is a runlist and about wrapper cookbooks.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Does this mean I have to create another cookbook, and use the java cookbook inside that? Is this the concept of a wrapper?

Comment: Yes it's the idea, you may modify the original cookbook but it quickly turn into a mess when you want to upgrade it, a wrapper is the best way in my point of view (Google around this, you'll find blog post and examples)

Comment: thanks for the help. I will come back with a comment - if i need more help. Thanks.

Comment: so the EDIT#1 that I was trying is not the right approach, is the correct? or do you think that should work too.

Comment: See mark's link, his answer on the other question is far more complete and should help you, but I think you really should practice chef with a more easy task (the Java install involves many things system wide) before to get comfortable with how chef works. Try http://learn.chef.io as a starting point if not already done.

Comment: your response does not really address his issue of install version 8 of the JDK. it is simpler to install version 7 especially if you use the `openjdk` flavor. it exists in the repo for most linux distros. Installing JDK8 is not really in most of them yet.

Comment: @d4v3y0rk See comment just above yours. My answer was targetting the first version of the question. At all it could be deleted and the question marked as duplicate.