# Chef-Client tries to install Java on Windows but it is already installed

Tags: windows, installation, chef-infra, cookbook

I'm new to Chef and want to install Java on a windows machine with it.

There is a ready-to-use [Java cookbook](https://github.com/agileorbit-cookbooks/java) I'm using.

So I wrote a wrapper cookbook, as mentioned in [another question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28776899/can-the-java-cookbook-be-used-to-install-a-local-copy-of-oracle-java).

I added the java-cookbook-dependencies and used the following attributes at

### attribute/java.rb

```
normal['java']['jdk_version'] = '7'
normal['java']['install_flavor'] = 'windows'
normal['java']['windows']['url'] = 'http://myurl/java/jdk-7u75-windows-x64.exe'
```

So after uploading the cookbook and adding it into the runlist Java gets installed and is available. But whenever I run the chef-client, it tries to install the JDK from the file again.

### So my question:

Am I missing some configuration to check for an already installed version? For my understanding, this should be done in the [given cookbook](https://github.com/agileorbit-cookbooks/java), but Im not sure if it is.

I also tried to declare a package name, but this does not change anything.

```
normal['java']['windows']['package_name'] = 'OracleJDK7u75'
```

Here the (relevant) output after starting the chef client with knife:

```
WindowsPC [2015-04-10T14:38:06+02:00] INFO: Processing remote_file[c:/chef/cache/jdk-7u75-windows-x64.exe]action create (java::windows line 45)
WindowsPC [2015-04-10T14:38:08+02:00] INFO: Processing windows_package[OracleJDK7u75] action install (java::windows line 71)
WindowsPC [2015-04-10T14:38:09+02:00] INFO: Installing windows_package[OracleJDK7u75] version latest
WindowsPC [2015-04-10T14:38:09+02:00] INFO: Starting installation...this could take awhile.
WindowsPC
WindowsPC ================================================================================
WindowsPC Error executing action `install` on resource 'windows_package[OracleJDK7u75]'
WindowsPC ================================================================================
WindowsPC
WindowsPC Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed
WindowsPC ------------------------------------
WindowsPC Expected process to exit with [0, 42, 127], but received '1603'
WindowsPC ---- Begin output of start "" /wait "c:\chef\cache\jdk-7u75-windows-x64.exe" /s  & exit %%ERRORLEVEL%% ----
WindowsPC STDOUT:
WindowsPC STDERR:
WindowsPC ---- End output of start "" /wait "c:\chef\cache\jdk-7u75-windows-x64.exe" /s  & exit %%ERRORLEVEL%% ----
WindowsPC Ran start "" /wait "c:\chef\cache\jdk-7u75-windows-x64.exe" /s  & exit %%ERRORLEVEL%% returned 1603
WindowsPC
WindowsPC Cookbook Trace:
WindowsPC ---------------
WindowsPC c:/chef/cache/cookbooks/windows/libraries/windows_package.rb:109:in `install_package'
WindowsPC c:/chef/cache/cookbooks/windows/libraries/windows_package.rb:31:in `block in <class:WindowsCookbookPackage>'
WindowsPC
WindowsPC Resource Declaration:
WindowsPC ---------------------
WindowsPC # In c:/chef/cache/cookbooks/java/recipes/windows.rb
WindowsPC
WindowsPC  71: windows_package node['java']['windows']['package_name'] do
WindowsPC  72:   source cache_file_path
WindowsPC  73:   checksum node['java']['windows']['checksum']
WindowsPC  74:   action :install
WindowsPC  75:   installer_type :custom
WindowsPC  76:   options "/s #{additional_options}"
WindowsPC  77: end
WindowsPC
WindowsPC Compiled Resource:
WindowsPC ------------------
WindowsPC # Declared in c:/chef/cache/cookbooks/java/recipes/windows.rb:71:in `from_file'
WindowsPC
WindowsPC windows_cookbook_package("OracleJDK7u75") do
WindowsPC   provider Chef::Provider::WindowsCookbookPackage
WindowsPC   action [:install]
WindowsPC   retries 0
WindowsPC   retry_delay 2
WindowsPC   default_guard_interpreter :default
WindowsPC   declared_type :windows_package
WindowsPC   cookbook_name "java"
WindowsPC   recipe_name "windows"
WindowsPC   source "c:/chef/cache/jdk-7u75-windows-x64.exe"
WindowsPC   installer_type :custom
WindowsPC   options "/s "
WindowsPC   package_name "OracleJDK7u75"
WindowsPC   timeout 600
WindowsPC   success_codes [0, 42, 127]
WindowsPC end
WindowsPC
WindowsPC [2015-04-10T14:38:14+02:00] INFO: Running queued delayed notifications before re-raising exception
WindowsPC [2015-04-10T14:38:14+02:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
WindowsPC [2015-04-10T14:38:14+02:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
WindowsPC [2015-04-10T14:38:14+02:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to c:/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
WindowsPC [2015-04-10T14:38:14+02:00] FATAL: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: windows_package[OracleJDK7u75] (java::windows line 71) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0, 42, 127], but received '1603'
WindowsPC ---- Begin output of start "" /wait "c:\chef\cache\jdk-7u75-windows-x64.exe" /s  & exit %%ERRORLEVEL%% ----
WindowsPC STDOUT:
WindowsPC STDERR:
WindowsPC ---- End output of start "" /wait "c:\chef\cache\jdk-7u75-windows-x64.exe" /s  & exit %%ERRORLEVEL%% ----
WindowsPC Ran start "" /wait "c:\chef\cache\jdk-7u75-windows-x64.exe" /s  & exit %%ERRORLEVEL%% returned 1603
ERROR: Failed to execute command on     WindowsPC return code 1
```

Thank you in advance

Bohne

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So as we already figured it out, java was installed on the first run and now we get the error, when we try to install it again.

**Possibility 1 :**

Windows package resource comes from [opscode windows cookbook](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/windows) and in README there is written:

> PLEASE NOTE - For proper idempotence the resource's package_name
>   should be the same as the 'DisplayName' registry value in the
>   uninstallation data that is created during package installation. The
>   easiest way to definitively find the proper 'DisplayName' value is to
>   install the package on a machine and search for the uninstall
>   information under the following registry keys:
>
> ```
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6464Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
> ```

I have java 7u72 installed and I have found a Registry key, where Windows stores information about the installation:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{64A3A4F4-B792-11D6-A78A-00B0D0170720}
```

The Windows cookbook tries to match the *DisplayName* value in Registry to the package_name of the resource. In my case it is "Java SE Development Kit 7 Update 72 (64-bit)". I guess in your case it should be "**Java SE Development Kit 7 Update 75 (64-bit)**" and not "OracleJDK7u75". So you may try to change your

```
normal['java']['windows']['package_name'] = 'Java SE Development Kit 7 Update 75 (64-bit)'
```

**Possibility 2:**

I have my own java cookbook to install java on windows and I do not follow the windows_package naming conventions. My java gets reinstalled every chef run. The difference with your windows_package declaration is that I have the following options:

```
/qn
```

Which means: "quiet, no UI". And "/s" seems like means nothing. You can see all the available parameters by running in command line:

```
jdk-7u75-windows-x64.exe /?
```

Comment: Thank you Draco! The Possibility 1 was the right guess. I also checked the registry and fixing the package_name to 'Java SE Development Kit 7 Update 75 (64-bit)' does the trick.

Comment: Possibility 1 solved the same issue for me - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Java package install error, rather than a problem with chef.

See:

- https://www.java.com/en/download/help/error_1603.xml
- http://www.adminarsenal.com/admin-arsenal-blog/beat-java-error-1603-when-deploying

I would suggest reproducing the problem without chef, by running the package manually. See what happens.

Sorry not a windows guy, perhaps others know more about this problem.

Comment: The first installation runs without problems from chef. The Error Code is obviously thrown, because java is already installed (when starting the installation file manually again it prompts a message "java is already installed, would you like to uninstall it?"). So my problem is, that chef doesn't realize, that java is already installed....it should not try to install it again :/

Answer (score 0):

From what I see in the cookbook, it appears that you are correct, and that there is no check in the Java cookbook for this.  Here's the pertinent part of the cookbook that I found for installing on Windows:

```
windows_package node['java']['windows']['package_name'] do
  source cache_file_path
  checksum node['java']['windows']['checksum']
  action :install
  installer_type :custom
  options "/s #{additional_options}"
end
```

In order to prevent it from executing if it were already in place, you would need to add an "only_if" or a "not_if" attribute to check to see if the installation has already occurred.

Comment: Sounds like a bug with the "windows_package" resource to me. "package" resource on other platforms don't have to test for the existence of a package.